# sysout-over-slf4j capturing System.out but not writing to logback

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I've configured sysout-over-slf4j with

```
SysOutOverSLF4J.sendSystemOutAndErrToSLF4J()
```

`System.out` and `System.err` are no longer showing up on the console, so it does seem to be capturing them. It is, however, not showing up in any of my loggers.

**Update re: configuration:**

I've tried this with various configurations, but here's the kitchen sink i tried:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/Users/arne/log/sandbox.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d\t%level\t[%thread]\t%logger{35}\t%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Since `SysOutOverSLF4J` seems to go to INFO and ERROR by default, I figured DEBUG should catch all. I just tried it with TRACE and still nothing. My simple test looks like this:

```
object LoggerTest extends App with LazyLogging {
  SysOutOverSLF4J.sendSystemOutAndErrToSLF4J()
  logger.debug("to log")
  System.out.print("to System.out")
  System.err.print("to System.err")
}
```

producing this output:

```
2015-04-24 09:23:16,859 [main] DEBUG u.o.l.s.c.SysOutOverSLF4JInitialiser - Your logging framework class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger should not need access to the standard println methods on the console, so you should not need to register a logging system package.
2015-04-24 09:23:16,869 [main] INFO  u.o.l.s.context.SysOutOverSLF4J - Replaced standard System.out and System.err PrintStreams with SLF4JPrintStreams
2015-04-24 09:23:16,872 [main] INFO  u.o.l.s.context.SysOutOverSLF4J - Redirected System.out and System.err to SLF4J for this context
2015-04-24 09:23:16,873 [main] DEBUG sandbox.LoggerTest$ - to log
```

> *Your logging framework class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger should not need access to the*

I assume the above should be a hint to my problem by I don't know what to make of it, since without `SysOutOverSLF4J` logback does not capture `STDOUT` or `STDERR` either, which is why I am using it in the first place.

Comment: And what does your setup/configuration look like?

Comment: I've added configuration, sample code and output. Hope that helps

Answer (score -3):

```
SysOutOverSLF4J.sendSystemOutAndErrToSLF4J(LogLevel.DEBUG, LogLevel.ERROR);
```

it should works!